# What is the cost to download/transfer data from Azure SQL database to local?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I am new to Azure SQL Server.

We have SQL Server database in Azure. We are stopping the Azure subscription as the web application that uses the Azure SQL database has been terminated.

We need to download/transfer the web application data from Azure SQL Server to our local storage.

Will it cost us to download/transfer/export the data present in Azure SQL Server database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, outbound data transfer costs but it is usually quite minimal.
Here is the pricing page: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/bandwidth/.
It'll depend slightly on your region, but the first 5 GB are free each month.